# Flutter DorpDownMenu selected item don't change

Tags: flutter

in this below code when i try change item on `DropDownMenu`, selected item don't change and selected item is first item of list

for example after selecting `bbbbbbb` i have `aaaaaaa` or selecting `ccccccc` i have `aaaaaaa`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()=>runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    home: _MyApp(),
  ),
);

class _MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState()=>_MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<_MyApp> {
  SessionsEntity sessionData;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<SessionsEntity>> _dropdownMenuItems;
    _dropdownMenuItems = buildDropdownMenuItems();
    sessionData = _dropdownMenuItems[0].value;

    return Scaffold(
      body: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            canvasColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: DropdownButton(
                items: _dropdownMenuItems,
                isDense: true,
                value: sessionData,
                onChanged: onChangeDropdownItem,
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: Text('please select item'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<SessionsEntity>> buildDropdownMenuItems() {
    List<SessionsEntity> sessions = [
      SessionsEntity(1, 'aaaaaaa', 1, 'a-a-a-a-a'),
      SessionsEntity(2, 'bbbbbbb', 2, 'b-b-b-b-b'),
      SessionsEntity(3, 'ccccccc', 2, 'c-c-c-c-c'),
    ];
    List<DropdownMenuItem<SessionsEntity>> items = List();
    for (SessionsEntity session in sessions) {
      items.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: session,
          child: Text(session.sessionName),
        ),
      );
    }
    return items;
  }

  onChangeDropdownItem(SessionsEntity selectedSession) {
    setState(() {
      sessionData = selectedSession;
    });
  }
}

class SessionsEntity {
  final int id;
  String sessionName;
  int sessionType;
  String dateTime;
  SessionsEntity(this.id, this.sessionName,this.sessionType, this.dateTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies at the below line.

`sessionData = _dropdownMenuItems[0].value;`

Since your are initializing `sessionData` variable every time in the `build()` method, the call to `setState()` has no effect.

Basically `setState()` calls the `build()` method again with the new data but when you initialize `sessionData` insiside `build()` it gets overwritten with same value every time `build()` is called.

You should declare the use the `_dropdownMenuItems` list as a class variable instead of inside `build()` and  use the `initState()` method to initialize the `_dropdownMenuItems` and `sessionData` variables only once. Here is an example -

```
class _MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState()=>_MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<_MyApp> {

  //Remove below line from build method
  List<DropdownMenuItem<SessionsEntity>> _dropdownMenuItems;
  SessionsEntity sessionData;

   @override
         void initState() {
         super.initState();
         _dropdownMenuItems = buildDropdownMenuItems();
         sessionData = _dropdownMenuItems[0].value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //Rest of the code remains same
  }
}
```

Comment: `The following assertion was thrown building _MyApp(dirty, dependencies:
[_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#eea77], _InheritedTheme], state: _MyAppState#f1da2):
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 608 pos 15: 'items == null ||
items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value ==
value).length == 1': is not true.`

Comment: I didn't realise that you had also declared `_dropdownMenuItems` list inside the `build` method. Please check the code in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following will help you. The sample widget is made for selecting a reason.

Sample widget code :

```
Widget dropdownReasons() {    
      return new DropdownButton<String>(
          value: _currentReason,
          items: _dropDownMenuItems,
          onChanged: changedDropDownItem);
    }
  }
```

The function below handles what to do when the drop down value is changed :

```
void changedDropDownItem(String selectedReason) {
    setState(() => _currentReason = selectedReason; // <-- This is the most important line
  }
```

Comment: please read my post again. i pasted some other code into my post

Comment: Problem is here : `value: sessionData`.  'value' is String whereas 'sessionData'  is of type SessionEntity. You'll have to get specific property from `SessionEntity` and assign it to the 'value' as  a string. Example : `sessionData = selectedCompany.name`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, this will work fine

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: new MyApp(),),
  );
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  SessionsEntity sessionData;
  List<DropdownMenuItem<SessionsEntity>> _dropdownMenuItems;

// Build method is called whenever there is change in the state or ui, so instead of initializing the dropdown menu items and initial selected value of dropdown menu in build method you should initialize it in initState method which is called only once.

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _dropdownMenuItems = buildDropdownMenuItems();
    sessionData = _dropdownMenuItems[0].value;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            canvasColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: DropdownButton(
                items: _dropdownMenuItems,
                isDense: true,
                value: sessionData,
                onChanged: onChangeDropdownItem,
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: Text('please select item'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  List<DropdownMenuItem<SessionsEntity>> buildDropdownMenuItems() {
    List<SessionsEntity> sessions = [
      SessionsEntity(1, 'aaaaaaa', 1, 'a-a-a-a-a'),
      SessionsEntity(2, 'bbbbbbb', 2, 'b-b-b-b-b'),
      SessionsEntity(3, 'ccccccc', 2, 'c-c-c-c-c'),
    ];
    List<DropdownMenuItem<SessionsEntity>> items = List();
    for (SessionsEntity session in sessions) {
      items.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: session,
          child: Text(session.sessionName),
        ),
      );
    }
    return items;
  }

  onChangeDropdownItem(SessionsEntity selectedSession) {
    setState(() {
      sessionData = selectedSession;
    });
  }
}


class SessionsEntity {
  final int id;
  String sessionName;
  int sessionType;
  String dateTime;
  SessionsEntity(this.id, this.sessionName,this.sessionType, this.dateTime);
}
```